# Server substitution. Emulating internet server

Tags: linux, networking, routing, iptables, openwrt

I have two networks sequent networks both hidden under own NAT  `192.168.31.0/24` -> `192.168.33.0/24` -> Internet

I have a TCP server on `192.168.33.35` and a client on `192.168.31.32`

A client does a TCP request to server located in the internet at `66.66.66.66`, for example. I want the last gateway `192.168.33.1` to send the request to `192.168.33.35` instead and trick the client.

The most feasible of what I tried is:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -d 66.66.66.66 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.33.35
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 192.168.33.35 -j SNAT --to-source 66.66.66.66
```

The server received the Syn packet and replied. But the source IP of the server response seems to remain `192.168.33.35` after passing the gateway. And packet gets lost received by `192.168.31.1` gateway.

Looks like SNAT part is not working.

What can I do to emulate/spoof the server with standard openWrt tools?

Comment: Are you emulating a server, or just trying to figure out how to spoof the path/destination/source of an ICMP packet?

Comment: @music2myear, I am emulating the server as I wrote in the header.

Comment: See, the headline of an article or title of a book summarizes the information in the article or book, it does not replace or contain unique information. Please treat questions here the same way: The title is a summary but should not contain unique information. The body of the question should contain ALL relevant and necessary information. Please edit the body of your question to make it more clear.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, exactly

Comment: @music2myear , actually, IP spoofing is the correct term. I was confused by the fact that I am not doing any adversary actions. And still, I can't find a solution (facepalm)

Answer (score 1):

This is what happens:

1. Your `192.168.33.35` server sees the Syn packet from `192.168.33.Z` (it's unaware of `192.168.31.0/24` network and sees the "WAN" address of the `192.168.31.1` gateway, I don't know what `Z` is) and replies to this address.
2. Its routing table says this address belongs to local network, so the response is destined to MAC address of `192.168.33.Z`.
3. Even if the response physically travels through the `192.168.33.1` machine, the gateway doesn't mangle with it because it is destined to MAC address of another machine.
4. `192.168.33.Z` sees the response from `192.168.33.35`. It expects one from `66.66.66.66` and doesn't know what to do.

Note it doesn't matter `192.168.33.Z` performs NAT (being `192.168.31.1` on its LAN side). The mechanism of failure is very similar to the one where [NAT loopback (hairpin NAT) is only partially set up](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/282094/108618).

You have to make your `192.168.33.35` server send responses to the MAC address of your `192.168.33.1` gateway.

- Either set a routing rule for `192.168.33.Z` (remember I don't know `Z`, you do; substitute the real number) or even for entire `192.168.33.0/24` network:

  ```
  # do this on the 192.168.33.35 machine
  route add -host 192.168.33.Z gw 192.168.33.1
  ```

  Note it will affect all communication from `192.168.33.35` to `192.168.33.Z`. In cases when `192.168.33.35` should act as `192.168.33.35` packets will be unnecessarily routed; it shouldn't break things though.
- Or let the `192.168.33.1` gateway perform not only DNAT but SNAT as well. This solution is basically the same as the one for NAT loopback in the already linked answer:

  ```
  # do this on the 192.168.33.1 gateway
  # you already have this line
  iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -d 66.66.66.66 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.33.35
  # this line is new
  iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -d 192.168.33.35 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.33.1
  ```

This fragment applies to your situation:

> Note that the NAT table in `iptables` is only used for the first packet of a connection. Later packets related to the connection are processed using the internal mapping tables established when the first packet was translated.

This means the second of your lines (`iptables … -j SNAT --to-source 66.66.66.66`) is irrelevant when you initiate a connection from a client. Later packets will be SNAT-ed and DNAT-ed properly because the first packet was.

---

I think if your first line

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -d 66.66.66.66 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.33.35
```

acted on the `192.168.31.1` gateway, it would do what you want for other clients from `192.168.31.0/24` without any additional tricks.

---

This second line of yours

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 192.168.33.35 -j SNAT --to-source 66.66.66.66
```

will apply if you initiate a connection *from* `192.168.33.35`. Internet servers rarely do this, so you may not need this rule at all. In case you do need it, remember that:

- the rule will only work if packets are routed through the `192.168.33.1` gateway where this rule acts, so to reach your local computers and to present to them as `66.66.66.66` you need to adjust the routing table on the `192.168.33.35` machine similarly as above;
- you cannot communicate as `66.66.66.66` with external hosts (beyond your network) because even if you managed to reach them acting as `66.66.66.66`, their response would get to the real `66.66.66.66`, not back to you.

Comment: Thank You so much for you reply. It clarified some mistakes to me. But I did not manage to do it with iptables even with the example You linked. I did it in another way.

Answer (score 0):

Did it with routing. Unfortunately it is less flexible in order to access the real server, but at least it works. Something like this:

```
root@192.168.33.1# route add -host 66.66.66.66 gw 192.168.33.35 dev br-lan
```

and on the server:

```
user@192.168.33.35# ip link add name s666 type dummy
user@192.168.33.35# ifconfig s666 66.66.66.66
user@192.168.33.35# ifconfig s666 up
```